# How to access celldata objects in sheets api

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm working on a google sheets integration project where I'd like to add formatted text to cells (bold, italic).  This needs to be for only part of the cell (e.g. only some of the text in the cell is **bold** )  I can see that this can be done though the CellData object, documented in the sheets api here:

[CellData](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/SheetsV4/CellData)

But I can't work out how to get an instance of these objects.  I'm using the sheets service to successfully get a SpreadSheet, Sheet and ValueRange objects, but I can't work out how to get through to the cell data objects themselves to use these methods.

Comment: Also note I'm interested in reading the formatting from inside cells in sheets (which have been imported from excel files)

Comment: When a part of value of a cell has several formats, you want to retrieve the formats. If my understanding is correct, how about retrieving [``textFormatRuns``](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#TextFormatRun)? The script is ``res = service.get_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, ranges: range, fields: fields)``. At that time, for example, ``fields`` is ``sheets(data(rowData(values(textFormatRuns,userEnteredValue))))``. ``range`` is A1Notation. I commented because I'm not sure whether this is what you want.

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for, how do you write a formatted value back again?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer including sample scripts. Could you please confirm it? If those samples were not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When a part of value of a cell has several formats, you want to retrieve the formats.
2. You want to put a value with several formats to a cell.

I understand your question as above. If my understanding is correct, how about these samples?

### 1. Retrieve value

When a part of value of a cell has several formats like below image,

[image]

the script for retrieving the values with the formats is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This sample script retrieves the value from the cell "A1" of "Sheet1".

```
spreadsheet_id = '### spreadsheet ID ###'
ranges = ['Sheet1!A1']
fields = 'sheets(data(rowData(values(textFormatRuns,userEnteredValue))))'
response = service.get_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, ranges: ranges, fields: fields)
```

#### Result:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "abcdefg"
                  },
                  "textFormatRuns": [
                    {
                      "format": {}
                    },
                    {
                      "format": {
                        "fontSize": 24,
                        "foregroundColor": {
                          "red": 1
                        },
                        "bold": true
                      },
                      "startIndex": 2
                    },
                    {
                      "format": {},
                      "startIndex": 5
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### 2. Put value

When a value with several formats is put to a cell, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This sample script puts the value to the cell "B1" of "Sheet1". As a sample, `update_cells` is used for this situation.

```
spreadsheet_id = '### spreadsheet ID ###'
requests = {requests: [
  update_cells: {
    fields: 'userEnteredValue,textFormatRuns',
    range: {sheet_id: 0, start_row_index: 0, end_row_index: 1, start_column_index: 1, end_column_index: 2},
    rows: [{values: [{user_entered_value: {
          string_value: 'abcdefg'},
          text_format_runs: [{format: {}}, {format: {font_size: 24, foreground_color: {red: 1}, bold: true}, start_index: 2}, {format:{}, start_index: 5}]
    }]}]
  }
]}
response = service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, requests, {})
```

- About `sheet_id: 0`, if you want to other sheet, please modify it.

#### Result:

[image]

### Note:

- These sample scripts supposes that your environment can use Sheets API.
- These are simple samples. So please modify them to your situation.

### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [textFormatRuns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#TextFormatRun)
- [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: This was helpful. You can also write the fields value as "sheets.data.rowData.values(textFormatRuns,userEnteredValue)".