# How to Get Hyperlinks Using Google Sheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access a hyperlink using the v4 API [ValueRenderOption param](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) (`valueRenderOption=FORMULA`). I have tried with both python's gsheets and cURL. Either way, I cannot seem to get the formula that will show a hyperlink. Below is a screenshot of the spreadsheet; note the cell containing the value `2` has its formula shown, as expected, but that the hyperlink to https://example.com is shown as "sup". Is there a new way that we are supposed to access the contents of hyperlinks?

[image]

gsheets:

```py
print(worksheet.acell('A2', value_render_option="FORMULA").value)
# sup
```

cURL:

```sh
URL="https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$SHEET_ID/values/%27Sheet1%27%21A2"
curl -X GET "$URL?valueRenderOption=FORMULA" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"

# output
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1001",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "Name",
      "Other"
    ],
    [
      "sup",
      "word"
    ],
    [
      "k",
      100
    ],
    [
      "=AVERAGE(1,2,3)",
      "k"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve a hyperlink which was set to a cell on Google Spreadsheet.

In this case, in the current stage, the hyperlink can be retrieved using the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API. And, it is required to use the field parameter for this request. By this, the hyperlink can be retrieved. The sample curl command is as follows.

As the sample situation, it supposes that the URL is set to a cell "A1" of "Sheet1" in Google Spreadsheet.

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]?ranges=Sheet1!A1&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink))))' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Result:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "hyperlink": "https://example.com/"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### For gspread:

At gspread, `requests` library is used as follows. The access token is retrieved from `credentials` of `gspread.authorize(credentials)`.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
access_token = credentials.access_token
url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]?ranges=Sheet1!A1&fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink))))'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
print(res.json())
```

Result:

```
{'sheets': [{'data': [{'rowData': [{'values': [{'hyperlink': 'https://example.com/'}]}]}]}]}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample, `sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink))))` is used as `fields`. About this, you can also use `sheets`. In this case, other values are included in the response values.
- At the sample, `Sheet1!A1` is used as the range. So please modify this range for your actual situation.
- In the current stage, when a hyperlinks is set to a part of texts in a cell and the several hyperlinks are set to a cell, unfortunately, those cannot be directly retrieved using Sheets API. At that time, as the current workaround, it is required to use Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653) Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't clicking at the time that showing formulas to see hyperlinks only works if they were created using `=HYPERLINK(...)`.

Comment: It's (now?) possible to extract multiple links from a cell using `fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/textFormatRuns/format/link/uri"` with the python API https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880090/648176. 
You get something like `{'sheets': [{'data': [{'rowData': [{'values': [{},{'textFormatRuns': [{'format': {'link': {'uri': 'https://google.com/first/'}}}, {'format': {}}, {'format': {'link': {'uri': 'https://google.com/second/'}}}]}]}]}]}]}`

Comment: @Fush Thank you for your comment. About `textFormatRuns`, this has already been able to be used in 2019. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54161948) When the URLs are required to be retrieved from the part of the text in a cell, this can be used. In this case, `hyperlink` is not included in the response. When the URL is retrieved from a cell, `hyperlink` can be used. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.