# Get value of link cell from Google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have hyperlinked values in a certain column of a Google Sheet. I want to retrieve the actual link text from each cell in that column. Using [gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/)'s `value_render_option='FORMULA'` for a cell does not retrieve the link value (only the text) nor does using the `Cell.input_value attribute (returns None)`.
Any idea how to get the link value preferably using `gspread` or another library?

```
val = sheet_instance.acell('F798', value_render_option='FORMULA').value
val = sheet_instance.acell('F798').input_value
```

Comment: Not familiar with gspread, but the property in the Google Sheets API is `hyperlink` https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData

Comment: I think that this thread might be useful for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63838821