# Get hyperlinks of Google Spreadsheet cells with Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 package in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-api, spreadsheet

I'm working on application, which uses [Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 via nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/) in .Net Core. I would like to retrieve some range of "values" from one Google Spreadsheet, in the code below:

```
SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
  ApplicationName = appName,
 });

  string spreadSheetName = config.AppSettings.Settings["SpreadSheet"].Value;
  string spreadsheetId = config.AppSettings.Settings["ListSpreadSheetId"].Value;
  string range = spreadSheetName + myRange;

  // API call
  SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

  
  ValueRange response = request.Execute();
  
  // values collection doesn't include hyperlinks, only readable text from spreadsheet
  IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
```

This works fine for retrieving cell values, but I would like to retrieve HYPERLINKS from spreadsheet as well (with provided solution I get only string, which plays the role of placeholder). There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838821/how-to-get-hyperlinks-using-google-sheets-api-v4) on SO, where one of provided answers is about specifying parameters in HTTP GET method, which is fine. I wouldn't mind to do this within my C# code, but it would at least break it consistency, because everything else I can do with Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 package. [Documentation for this package namespace](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsBaseServiceRequest-1.html) looks a bit complicated for me, and I can't find any part of it, where I can provide parameters for Get Request in it. Is it possible to achieve what I want with it as well?